# How to get table row data using check box in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help.I need to get all checked data from the table row using Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="gl in galleryDatas">
<td><input type="checkbox" name=""> {{$index+1}}</td>
<td><img ng-src="upload/{{gl.image}}" border="0" name="image" style="width:100px; height:100px;" /></td>
<td>{{gl.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here i need while user will clicked the check box the respective row data will retrieving into a array.Please help me.

Comment: Worth looking at this, the fiddle seems like what you want to achieve: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14835160/4045532](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14835160/4045532)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind to list of checkbox values with AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-to-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-change on the checkbox

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="clickedRow(gl.checked)" name="" ng-model="gl.checked"></td>
```

In controller,

```
$scope.clickedRow = function(checked) {
 if (checked) {
  //add to the list
   } else {
 // remove from list
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve by this process

in your controller:

```
$scope.galleryDatas = [
  {
        name: 'something',
        description: "name 1"
    },
    {
        name: 'another',
        description: "name 2"
    }
  ];

  $scope.checkedValue = [];

  $scope.saveInArray = function(index) {
    if($scope.galleryDatas[index].checked) {
      $scope.checkedValue.push($scope.galleryDatas[index]);
    } else {
       var newIndex = $scope.checkedValue.map(function(e) { return e.name; }).indexOf($scope.galleryDatas[index].name);
       // for compare instead of "name" you should use that field is unique. ie: e.uniqueField
       // and $scope.galleryDatas[index].uniqueField
       if(newIndex !== -1)
          $scope.checkedValue.splice(newIndex,1);
    }

  };
```

**N.B:** where checked row data store in `$scope.checkedValue` array and when unchecked then removed from `$scope.checkedValue` array

and Html:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="gl.checked" ng-click="saveInArray($index)"> {{$index+1}}</td>
```